# double android.location.Location.getLatitude()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, google-maps

the only reason i'm asking this again, is because i've tried all the answers and its not working for me i'm trying to get the current user location but it's not working so this is what i've been trying to do, btw i already setted up all the permissions neeeded and i keep getting the double android location.getlatitude on a null object reference error and fatal execption main , pleaaase help me
this my GPSTRACKER Java class code :

```
package com.example.nefissa.androidtest;

 import android.*;
 import android.Manifest;
 import android.app.Service;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
 import android.location.Location;
 import android.location.LocationListener;
 import android.location.LocationManager;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.os.IBinder;
 import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
 import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;


public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener{

private final Context context;

boolean isGPSEnabled =false;
boolean isNetworkEnabled =false;
boolean canGetLocation =false;

Location location;
protected LocationManager locationManager;



  public GPSTracker(Context context){
   this.context=context;
  }

// create a GetLocation Method //

public Location getLocation(){

    try{
        locationManager=(LocationManager) context.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(locationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        isNetworkEnabled=locationManager.isProviderEnabled(locationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ){


            if(isGPSEnabled){
                if(location==null){
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,100000,10,this);
                    if(locationManager!=null){
                          location=locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                    }
                  }
            }
               // if location is not found from GPS then it will found from network //
            if(location==null){
                if(isNetworkEnabled){
                           locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,100000,10,this);
                        if(locationManager!=null){
                              location=locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        }
                    }

            }
        }

    }catch(Exception e){

    }
    return location;
}




@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

}
}
```

and My Main Activity code :

```
package com.example.nefissa.androidtest;

 import android.location.Location;
 import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
  import android.os.Bundle;

 import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
 import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
  import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
   import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
   import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
 import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

 public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements     OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;
private GPSTracker gpsTracker;
private Location mLocation;
double latitude;
double longitude;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    gpsTracker= new GPSTracker(getApplicationContext());
    mLocation=gpsTracker.getLocation();
    latitude= mLocation.getLatitude();
    longitude= mLocation.getLongitude();


    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}


/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(latitude,longitude);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("you are here"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
  }
 }
```

Comment: Your problem is the awful and flawed GPSTracker example code. Stop using it and read some official Android documentation instead or have a look at the [Documentation section](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/1837/location#t=201703291427260931037) at StackOverflow.

Comment: I'm new to android developement, and i'm working on a project for school, and i found this example on net .. as i said i'm trying to get the user current location, can you please help me?

Comment: use some debugging , see the control flow plus you are using service as a service but as a normal class

Comment: The main problems are that 1) the device location may be unknown and then `getLastKnownLocation()` returns `null` 2) the code requests location updates with `requestLocationUpdates()` but doesn't use them in `onLocationChanged()`. You need to check for null locations to avoid crashes and get the location from `onLocationChanged()` if `getLastKnownLocation()` returned `null`. Those are the main issues and they are covered in many previous questions here, so I won't go into more details.

Answer (score 0):

After onMapReady is called, you'd better to initialize gpsTracker.

```
   gpsTracker= new GPSTracker(getApplicationContext());

   if(gpsTracker!=null){
       mLocation=gpsTracker.getLocation();
       latitude= mLocation.getLatitude();
       longitude= mLocation.getLongitude();
   }
```

And I think gpsTracker.getLocation have to change to logic. 
please read a android gps guide.

Comment: still doesn't work , i'm just trying to get the user location what do you think  I should do ?

Answer (score -1):

Try using

GPS Tracker

```
public GPSTracker(Activity activity) {
    this.mActivity = activity;
    getLocation();
}

public void getLocation() {
    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) mActivity
                .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (!isGPSEnabled || !isNetworkEnabled) {
            showSettingsAlert();
        } else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;
            if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mActivity, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mActivity, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(mActivity, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 1);
                } else {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("Network", "Network");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}




/**
 * Function to get latitude
 */
public double getLatitude() {
    if (location != null) {
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
    }

    // return latitude
    return latitude;
}

/**
 * Function to get longitude
 */
public double getLongitude() {
    if (location != null) {
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }

    // return longitude
    return longitude;
}


/**
 * Function to ic_check GPS/wifi enabled
 *
 * @return boolean
 */
public boolean canGetLocation() {
    return this.canGetLocation;
}
```

also from Activity call as

onCreate

```
//
gps = new GPSTracker(SignUpActivity.this);
        if (gps.canGetLocation) {
            lat = String.valueOf(gps.getLatitude());
            lng = String.valueOf(gps.getLongitude());
        }
```

Comment below if you still got issue

Comment: what was the error!! am still using that with no issue